# When OneDrive desktop app creates a new main folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, sync

I am working on 3 tenants and on both of them i am syncing some document libraries. now i have noted that OneDrive desktop app has created 3 main folders for me under username as follow:-

[image]

so can i say that OneDrive (at-least by default) will create a main folder for each tenant, and not for each site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using OneDrive sites, yes it will create it as 'OneDrive - tenantName'. Document Libraries from SPO sites will go into a folder with the name of the tenant.